# BSD C server not comparing string from buffer

Tags: c, bsd

So I am trying to compare the buffer to a string with strcmp. I want the server to respond in a special way when something the client says **"man"** and otherwise just reply with got it. I cant see what i am doing wrong, but my output is always "**got it**" and not **man** even when i input **man** from the client side.

```
void dostuff (int sock)
{
   int n;
   char buffer[256];
   bzero(buffer,256);
   n = read(sock,buffer,255);
    //make list match each get text and match to user
    if (n < 0) error("ERROR reading from socket");
    if (!strcmp ( buffer, "man" )) n = write(sock,"you are manly",18);
    else{  printf("Here is the message: %s\n",buffer);
        n = write(sock,"got it",18);};
           //n = write(sock,"you are gay",18);

        if (n < 0) error("ERROR writing to socket");
     /*

   if (n < 0) error("ERROR reading from socket");
   printf("Here is the message: %s\n",buffer);
   n = write(sock,"got it",18);
   if (n < 0) error("ERROR writing to socket");*/
}
```

Comment: So is this C or C++ finally? Don't tag it C++ if it isn't.

Comment: BSD question shouldn't be tagged `linux`, and no C++ in here.

Comment: Have you tried running the server in the debugger or looked to see what it says via the printf?

Comment: can you show us the client code?
the odds are that buffer contains "man"+garbage

Comment: Please post the client code so we can provide help.

Comment: here is the client code http://pastebin.com/6KZsbDp5

Comment: and server code http://pastebin.com/pX7DSSbf

Comment: At some point you'll want to upvote and/or accept the answers that helped you out the most.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `fgets()` in the client to acquire the string to send to the server. The string will have a `\n` and the end and won't match "man".

To remove the `\n` at the end of the buffer you can do something like this:

`strtok (buffer, "\n");` which will replace the `\n` with a `NULL` so your `strcmp()` will work.

Comment: thank you dude, do you know of a way to stream images or video? i dont quite understand how to do this with bitstreams.

Comment: You send your binary data the same as you would text data. Just make sure you open your file to read binary data, read chunks into a buffer, send to buffer on the socket. Look into open(), read() and write().

Comment: When streaming data, you need to do it in a way that doesn't make assumption about the size and/or termination of the stream. ALWAYS make sure the sending part tells the receiver how much it should expect and vice versa.

Comment: so i have to convert the file to binary or does the method open read does that automatically?

Comment: also how do i communicate how much the receiver should expect, does that mean i have to write the same buffer size on the other end? i think i already did that. thank you so much for your help.

Comment: See http://www.codingunit.com/c-tutorial-binary-file-io Your file will already be in binary format if it's an image or video. As Morten said, we sending be sure to tell the receiver how many bytes you are sending.

Comment: To let the receiver know how many bytes to read, you will have to include include the number of bytes to be read in the packet. This is usually done by pre-pending the number of bytes in the packet. Then the receiver can read this "header" first, then read the rest of the packet now that it knows how many bytes to expect.

Comment: amusing, so its similar to a router packet, in a sense that there is a structure on how the blob of data is treated.

Comment: where can i find more info about this structure?

Comment: That should be asked as another StackOverflow question.

Answer (score 2):

`strcmp` assumes C zero-terminated strings, which you don't always get from a socket (which, assuming TCP, is a stream of bytes and can split that stream in an arbitrary way when returning data to you).

Check the size of the chunk received (`n` in your code) to be at least `3` then use `memcmp` with explicit size argument.